# Dynamically assign ID and attach data in JavaScript & jQuery using two nested for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some trouble to get through this below jsfiddle task. 
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/anderrob/pc3j22v9/2/)

I want to do the same function using dynamic id.
I tried so many methods, but nothing works.
Please don't recommend to change the infrastructure. The page has been already designed the same kind of structure.
I need to achieve this same kind of function using two nested for loops with dynamic id.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="beforeDiv0">
  <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px;">
    <label for="Amount" style="font-weight:bold;">Amount:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="textboxId0" value="1000" />
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="col-md-4" id="beforeDiv1">
  <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 5px;">
    <label for="Amount" style="font-weight:bold;">Amount:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="textboxId1" value="1000" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript & jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
                   var newAmount = parseFloat(1000) + parseFloat(5);

        for(var id=0; id<3; id++){
            for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {

                var html = '<tr style="height:50px;">';
                html = html + '<td class="td-Amount" style="text-align: right; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">';
                html = html + 'Original: '+ '<span  id="OrginalAmount' +  i + '">' + 1000 + '</span><br/>' + 'New: <span  id="Output' + id + "" +  i + '">' + newAmount + '</span></td>';
                html = html + '</tr>';

                $(html).insertAfter("#beforeDiv" + id);

                //var abc = id + "" + i;
                //var xyz = '#textboxId' + id;
                //var zyx = "Output"+id+""+i;

            }
        }

        var myArr = new Array();
        var myArr2 = new Array();

        for(var id=0; id<3; id++){
            var xyz = '#textboxId' + id;
            myArr[id] = id;

                for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
                    myArr2[i] = i;

                    var calc = myArr[id] + "" + myArr2[i];
                    var zyx = "Output" + calc;

                    //below line is for dynamic id retrieval
                    /*
          $(xyz).on("click change paste keyup", function() {
                        var x = parseFloat(1000);
                        var y = parseFloat($(this).val());
                        var AmtChange = x + y;
                        document.getElementById(zyx).innerHTML = AmtChange;
                    });
          */
          $("#textboxId0").on("click change paste keyup", function() {
                        var x = parseFloat(1000);
                        var y = parseFloat($(this).val());
                        var AmtChange = x + y;
                        document.getElementById("Output01").innerHTML = AmtChange;
                      document.getElementById("Output02").innerHTML = AmtChange;
                    });

          $("#textboxId1").on("click change paste keyup", function() {
                        var x = parseFloat(1000);
                        var y = parseFloat($(this).val());
                        var AmtChange = x + y;
                        document.getElementById("Output11").innerHTML = AmtChange;
                      document.getElementById("Output12").innerHTML = AmtChange;
                    });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `Please don't recommend to change the infrastructure`  That is a big shame, as this could really be cleaned up & made much simpler.

Comment: @Keith, Actually those infrastructure was already developed by someone, not by me. Maintenance is one hell of a task in software developing. If i touch the infrastructure it will affect the whole system.

Comment: You are using jQuery, id is not the only selector available to you. Looking at the script presented, it looks like you are not worried about using tons of code for trivial purposes. Just assign the text boxes a class then collect that class in an array. BTW most of that code can be replaced if you use the input event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code, and considered your comments, and if I understand you correctly, then something like this is what you are after:

```
$('input[id^=textboxId]').on("click change paste keyup", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace(/\D/g,'');
    var x = parseFloat(1000);
    var y = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var AmtChange = x + y;
    /**
     * The following could not really be simplified, because
     * there are no defining data- attributes, or anything
     * to identify the table rows as belonging to the textbox.
     * When I tried to simplify the selection of "output" spans,
     * a span with id Output111 would have been matched by Output11
     * and Output1.
     */
    $('#beforeDiv' + id).nextUntil('br').each(function(i,el){
      $('span[id^=Output]', this).text(AmtChange);
    });
});
```

I tested this on Codepen: https://codepen.io/skunkbad/pen/ayeVLp

Comment: Thank you very much, You are awesome. This is exactly what I am looking. Anyways how can I approach if the textboxId & Output do not have the same type of number. Such as textboxId1 wants to change Output90 so on series. This is just for knowledge. You actually give the correct answer for my question. Thanks again.

Comment: My answer would change Output90, as long as it was inside one of the table rows immediately following the textboxId1. In the future though, it's highly recommended that you use data- attributes. All of this would have been super easy if you had `data-id="something"`, ya know? Anyways, I'm  off to the hospital, so if you message back it might be a while ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. If I ask more regarding this, maybe it will get off the topic of this question. If I need more clarifications and issues I will start it with a new question. Thank you very much....